# Open Trip Planner What is the correct url to use?

Tags: opentripplanner

I have just built and installed Open Trip Planner. I am quite confused as to how to acess the rest api.

Following [This](https://github.com/opentripplanner/OpenTripPlanner/wiki/TwoMinutes) example, it says I should be able to make a rest query on my api at

```
http://otp.markware.net:9090/otp-rest-servlet/ws/metadata
```

but I get a Grizzly Not Found.saying the path does not exist.

I can, however, get an XML Response back from

```
http://otp.markware.net:9090/otp
```

which is

```
<serverInfo>
<serverVersion>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<major>1</major>
<minor>0</minor>
<incremental>0</incremental>
<qualifier>SNAPSHOT</qualifier>
<commit>c3ab14e3632d5c875d031687a8eb58bcb57f12b3</commit>
<describe>opentripplanner-0.9.1-2594-gc3ab14e</describe>
<commit_time>30.06.2014 @ 23:35:13 UTC</commit_time>
<build_time>06.07.2014 @ 04:21:20 UTC</build_time>
</serverVersion>
<cpuName>Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5606 @ 2.13GHz</cpuName>
<nCores>8</nCores>
</serverInfo>
```

The documentation simply states to check out `http://otp.markware.net:9090/` after starting the server, I just get a blank page

What is the correct URL to use for the version I have built for the Web interface?

This is the Log showing the 404

```
     java -Xmx6G -jar target/otp.jar -p 9090 --server
    07:33:24.405 INFO (GraphServiceImpl.java:86) attempting to automatically register routerIds []
    07:33:24.410 INFO (GraphServiceImpl.java:87) graph files will be sought in paths relative to /var/otp/graphs
    07:33:24.410 INFO (GraphServiceFileImpl.java:232) registering routerId ''
    07:33:24.411 INFO (GraphServiceFileImpl.java:172) Loading graph...
    07:33:24.421 INFO (MavenVersion.java:53) Parsed Maven artifact version: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT => MavenVersion(1, 0, 0, SNAPSHOT, c3ab14e3632d5c875d031687a8eb58bcb57f12b3) UID=-1000000
    07:33:24.694 INFO (Graph.java:658) Graph version: MavenVersion(1, 0, 0, SNAPSHOT, c3ab14e3632d5c875d031687a8eb58bcb57f12b3)
    07:33:24.695 INFO (Graph.java:659) OTP version:   MavenVersion(1, 0, 0, SNAPSHOT, c3ab14e3632d5c875d031687a8eb58bcb57f12b3)
    07:33:24.695 INFO (Graph.java:676) This graph was built with the currently running version and commit of OTP.
    07:35:46.021 INFO (Graph.java:628) Main graph read. |V|=892461 |E|=2193825
    07:35:53.572 INFO (GraphIndex.java:88) Indexing graph...
    07:35:56.242 INFO (GraphIndex.java:137) Done indexing graph.
    07:35:56.249 INFO (GraphUpdaterConfigurator.java:69) Using configurations:
    07:35:56.249 INFO (OTPServer.java:65) Wiring up and configuring server.
    07:35:56.265 INFO (GrizzlyServer.java:48) Starting OTP Grizzly server on ports 9090 (HTTP) and 8081 (HTTPS) of interface 0.0.0.0
    07:35:56.266 INFO (GrizzlyServer.java:50) Base path is X, graphs are at /var/otp/graphs
    07:35:56.897 INFO (ApplicationHandler.java:353) Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.8 2014-04-29 01:25:26...
    07:35:58.483 WARN (PropertiesHelper.java:321) There is no way how to transform value "true" [java.lang.Boolean] to type [java.lang.String].
    07:35:59.397 INFO (NetworkListener.java:721) Started listener bound to [0.0.0.0:9090]
    07:35:59.409 INFO (NetworkListener.java:721) Started listener bound to [0.0.0.0:8081]
    07:35:59.417 INFO (HttpServer.java:298) [HttpServer] Started.
    07:35:59.417 INFO (GrizzlyServer.java:108) Grizzly server running.
    javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found
            at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:266)
            at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
            at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
            at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
            at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
            at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
            at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
            at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:252)
            at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1023)
            at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:364)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler$1.run(HttpHandler.java:217)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved ..

For the map instance, you have to add the index.html after the url. it does not default to the home page

http://otp.markware.net:9090/index.html